# A two-point boundary problem (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Would you know if the following ODE admit analytical solutions:
$F(x)F''(x)=D(x)$ with $x\in (0,1), F(0)=0, F'(1)=0$ and where D is a continuous, negative  function such  that $D(0)=D(1)=0$?
Does it represent any physical process?
Thanks by advance for any comments.

Comment: What do you mean by "analytical solutions"?

Comment: I mean by that a closed-form solution (i.e. that can be expressed analytically in terms of a finite number of certain "well-known" functions). Apologies for the confusion.